# PhpMyAdmin brute force attack

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have been using phpmyadmin on the public internet. The password I used is strong consisting of numbers, symbols and letters. However, I want to know if phpmyadmin deters brute force attacks? If not, how do I secure my phpmyadmin instance on the public internet from brute force login attempts?

Answer (score 3):

Phpmyadmin is a great administration tool . It comes with security patches . To protect , change the "phpmyadmin" path to something unknow like - "www.example.com/87-xn/index.php" something like that . Keep checking on updates and security patches . Don't give user id as only admin . Change the both to something unusual and strong enough ! That's all ...